Understanding Flatten[list, {i,j}]
Can someone please explain what Flatten[list,{i,j}] does?
For example:
list= {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 
   0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}}

Flatten[list,{3,2}]

outputs {{1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1}}
I understand that it has grouped together list[[i]][[1]][[1]] for $i \in {1,4}$ and then groups together list[[i]][[2]][[1]] for $i \in {1,4}$ and so on. But I don't understand the reasoning behind why {$3,2$} would specify this sort of Flattening?

Consider:
a = Array[b, {3, 3, 2}]


Now, Flatten[a,{2}] groups together all elements with the same second indices:

Similar, Flatten[a,{3}] groups together all elements with the same third index:

Finally, Flatten[a,{3,2}] first groups together all third indices and sub sequentially all second indices:

And Flatten[a,{2,3}] first gather all equal second indices and subsequently all third indices:


This doesn't seem to be documented and I fail to find a duplicate, so let me post an answer. The answer is simple: it's the shorthand for Flatten[list, {{3, 2}, {1}}]:
Flatten[list, {{3, 2}, {1}}] == Flatten[list, {3, 2}]
(* True *)

As to the meaning of Flatten[list, {{3, 2}, {1}}], it's well dicussed in:
Flatten command: matrix as second argument
